# c++ multiple definitions of operator<<

Tags: c++, overriding, iostream, operator-keyword

I am attempting to override the `<<` operator for a class.  The purpose is basically to implement a `toString()` like behavior for my class, so that sending it to `cout` will produce useful output.  Using a dummy example, I have the code below.  When I attempt to compile, I get the foollowing error:

```
$ g++ main.cpp Rectangle.cpp
/tmp/ccWs2n6V.o: In function `operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, CRectangle const&)':
Rectangle.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, CRectangle const&)'
/tmp/ccLU2LLE.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
```

I can't figure out why this is happening.  my code is below:

Rectangle.h:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CRectangle {
    private:
        int x, y;
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const CRectangle& r);
    public:
        void set_values (int,int);
        int area ();
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const CRectangle& r){
    return out << "Rectangle: " << r.x << ", " << r.y;
}
```

Rectangle.cpp:

```
#include "Rectangle.h"

using namespace std;

int CRectangle::area (){
    return x*y;
}

void CRectangle::set_values (int a, int b) {
    x = a;
    y = b;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Rectangle.h"

using namespace std;

int main () {
    CRectangle rect;
    rect.set_values (3,4);
    cout << "area: " << rect.area();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You're breaking the **one definition rule**. A quick-fix is:

```
inline ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const CRectangle& r){
    return out << "Rectangle: " << r.x << ", " << r.y;
}
```

Others are:

- declaring the operator in the header file and moving the implementation to `Rectangle.cpp` file.
- define the operator inside the class definition.

.

```
class CRectangle {
    private:
        int x, y;
    public:
        void set_values (int,int);
        int area ();
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const CRectangle& r){
          return out << "Rectangle: " << r.x << ", " << r.y;
        }
};
```

Bonus:

- use include guards
- remove the `using namespace std;` from the header.

Comment: *In the case of member definition:* If there is another class definition above the `CRectangle` and in the `overload<<` it uses the `<<` of `CRectangle` then there are issues. Even when doing a forward declaration of `CRectangle`! Any idea why?

Answer (score 27):

You are putting the *definition* of a function in a `.h` file, which means that it will appear in every translation unit, violating the One Definition Rule (=> you defined `operator<<` in every object module, so the linker doesn't know which is "the right one").

You can either:

- write just the *declaration* of your operator (i.e. its prototype) in the .h file and move its definition to `rectangle.cpp`
- make `operator<<` `inline` - `inline` functions are allowed to be defined more than once, as long as all the definitions are identical.

(Also, you should use header guards in your includes.)