# C++ namespacing to maintain old code

Tags: c++

I am writing a new REST router for an application. It has some old C++ classes called `Route` and so forth. I've created some new classes, namely (you guessed it) `Route` and `RouteManager`. There are literally 0 namespaces used in this entire application. So I figured by introducing my own namespace (`WebRouter`) I could code while keeping the old code in the project.

Obviously this didn't work. My compiler (C++98) is complaining about things that are already defined (`Route` and the cout overload). This is how I tried to accomplish my goal of keeping the old `Route` class while namespacing a new `Route` class.

**Route.hpp**

```
namespace WebRouter {
    // complains this is defined, which it is for the old Route..
    class Route {
        private:
        protected:
        public:
            string uri;
            string method;
            Route(string uri, string method);
            ~Route();
    };
}
// complains this is already defined, which it is for the old Route..
ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, WebRouter::Route const &route) { 
    os << "--- Route ---" << endl;
    os << "- URI: " << route.uri << endl;
    os << "- Method: " << route.method << endl;
    os << "-------------" << endl;
    return os;
}
```

**Route.cpp**

```
#include "Route.hpp"
using namespace WebRouter;

Route::Route(string uri, string method){
    this->uri = uri;
    this->method = method;
}
Route::~Route(){}
```

**RouteManager.hpp**

```
namespace WebRouter {
    class RouteManager {
        private:
            vector<Route> RouteVector;
        protected:
        public:
            RouteManager();
            ~RouteManager();
            Route* FindRoute(string uri, string method);
    };
}
```

**RouteManager.cpp**

```
#include "RouterManager.hpp"
using namespace WebRouter;

RouteManager::RouteManager() {}
RouteManager::~RouteManager() {}
```

The specific error is

`multiple definition of 'global constructors keyed to 2343_2__zoidfiosdiof**WebRouter**5**Route**E'`

This happens whether I do `using` or prefix with `WebRouter::`

Comment: `using namespace WebRouter;` well that's your problem right here.

Comment: just dont be lazy. The `using` will just make you have a `Router` and a `Router` that are actually two differnt things. Isnt `Router` vs `WebRouter::Router` much easier to distinguish?

Comment: What happens if you get rid of `using namespace WebRouter` and instead prefix your functions in `RouteManager.cpp` with `WebRouter::`?

Comment: Sorry friends but removing the `using` and prefixing with `WebRouter::` does not accomplish anything. It still complains to me `multiple definition of 'global constructors keyed to (gibberish text)WebRouter Route`

Comment: @JDoe.: You have to remove `using WebRouter;` from _all_ header files, not just this one

Comment: The idiomatic way would be to just declare the namespace in the CPP file again, like `namespace WebRouter{ Route::Route(...){}  Route::~Route(){}  }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things should or must be changed (we don't have all your source files to check that):

1. Don't use `using namespace WebRouter`, as several comments state it's a better policy to use `WebRouter::`
2. Your `Route` constructor and destructor definitions should also go inside of the `WebRouter` namespace in the cpp file.
3. The output stream overload for the `Route` class can also go inside of the class scope as friend and defined inside of the namespace.

Comment: Well after removing the overload, everything compiles fine (even as per my original code). However if I put the overload within the `WebRouter` namespace in the `Route.hpp` file, it is still the only thing it's complaining about...

Comment: have you declared the function as `friend ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, WebRouter::Route const &route);` inside of the Route class?

Comment: Yes. All this would do is give me access to private variables. It still thinks it's been defined twice. At this point it doesn't even look like it has anything to do with the old classes.

Comment: Yep definitely something fishy going on. I renamed it to `Route2` and same problems =/

Comment: If the overload of the output operator for the WebRouter::Route class is defined inside of the namespace, there is no reason to be double defined. Something else might be wrong.

Comment: It is definitely being double defined. `RouteManager.hpp` includes `Route.hpp` and `Route.cpp` includes `Route.hpp`. Thus the operator was double defined. I moved the entire thing into the class header and now it works. Lesson learned. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802536/c-multiple-definitions-of-operator)  . Also maybe that's what your 3rd point meant, but I didn't understand.

Comment: @JDoe. Then, definitely yes, it was double defined.